# AppEngine datastore bug - indexes are not synced

Tags: database, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I encountered the strangest thing just now:

I tried to put an entity into Cloud Datastore.
The entity didn't reach the database, but it DOES return when searching for it by index.

I mean:

`Select * from EntityType` -> Doesn't return the row (although other rows return)

`Select * from EntityType where entityName = "xxx"` -> DOES return the row (which didn't return in the previous query)

EDIT:

Both queries still return inconsistent result even over an hour after the Put()

Comment: Are you sure this is not just eventual consistency? If you try the first query again, does it now work?

Comment: Agree with @Daniel, unless you are getting via a key or using an ancestor query, inconsistancies are more likely to be a result of eventual consistency

Comment: I tried both queries 10 minutes after the Put() operation. Is it a reasonable period of time for inconsistency?

Comment: 20 minutes after the Put() - still inconsistent

Comment: Have you tried a get() on the item, then do the query.  If that makes a difference then it is definately eventual consistancy kicking in.

Comment: Can you add the exact code of your queries?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of eventual consistency - while the Entity is synchronously written and is guaranteed to be consistent for lookups, the indexes of the entity including the Kind index are updated asynchronously.

Normally this is resolved in milliseconds, but in rare situations it could extend to seconds or even an hour.